# check if an attribute of a class is assigned to a instance

Tags: python, class, if-statement, attributes

i'm making a little game for fun and i ran into an issue, how can i see if the email of a member is assigned to a instance?

file1:

```
if "test1@gmail.com" in file2:
   print("ok"
else:
   print("not ok")
```

file2:

```
player1 = Player("testName1", "test1@gmail.com", "testpwd1"
player2 = Player("testName2", "test2@gmail.com", "testpwd2"
player3 = Player("testName3", "test3@gmail.com", "testpwd3"
player4 = Player("testName4", "test4@gmail.com", "testpwd4"
```

Comment: You should *know* which attribute to check, not simply blindly looking if *some* attribute has the value you are looking for.

Comment: Are you *importing* `file2` as a module? You probably don't want 4 different `player` variables, but rather a list or dict (whose values you can iterate over) that contains the 4 players.

Comment: i am, like if someone login, it will check if his email already an attribute of a player (character), if not it will do something, if yes an other thing, could you help me?

Comment: Unfortunately - for you - this is not a tutorial site. But you will find these basic concepts in the first chapters of the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

overriding the `__contains__` method will do the trick.

So:

```py
def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.email
```

Edit:

If for some reason you don't care which attribute contains the value, this will work:

```py
def __contains__(self, key):
    return key in list(self.__dict__.values())
```

Comment: i'm not good with python classes, what will this do? edit: never mind i got it, thx, but now i need to specify the instance, like : "player_1.__contains("testgmail.com", and i want to check on all instances, what do i need to do?

Comment: First of all, you wouldn't explicitly call the __contians__ method. The `a in object` automatically calls the method.
Edit:
If you're always checking the same attribute just hard code it in the __contians__ method. If you don't want to check the same variable each time, I think you might be taking the wrong approach, it's a bit strange to use the "in" keyword in a dynamic way

Answer (score 0):

If you put `Players` in a list then you could use a dictionary to index that list. This example lets you look up by name and email at the same time.

file2.py

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, email, pwd):
        self.name = name.lower()
        self.email = email.lower()
        self.pwd = pwd
        
players = [
    Player("testName1", "test1@gmail.com", "testpwd1"),
    Player("testName2", "test2@gmail.com", "testpwd2"),
    Player("testName3", "test3@gmail.com", "testpwd3"),
    Player("testName4", "test4@gmail.com", "testpwd4")
]

# index to lookup up player by name or email

player_index = {player.name:player for player in players}
player_index.update({player.email:player for player in players})
```

file1.py

```
import file2

if file2.player_index.get("test1@mail.com".lower(), None) is not None:
    print("ok")
else:
    print("not ok")
```

It would be common to place that players list in some other data structure like a CSV file or even a pickled file. Assuming you want to update players dynamically, it becomes awkward to represent them as class instances in a .py file. But that's an enhancement for another time.

Comment: it says that the object is not subscriptable and i don't know what that mean xd

Comment: @ENDERastronaute - sorry about that. I hashed up 2 versions of sample tests and ended up with a dictionary lookup when it should have been attribute access.